# Mesh generation algorithm gives visual artifacts

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, graphics, mesh

Right now I am trying to implement terrain generation. I am using msvc visual studio 2019. And when I got to decreasing level of details in my function, generation started to be very glitchy. Everything is fine when I am not using any of level of details decreasing values. But everything changes after 1 and more - generation starts to be glitchy and generates atifacts. Here is some examples.

This one is correct as it should be. In my function this stands for parameter 0 in LevelOfDetails.
[image: LevelOfDetails = 0]

And Incorect examples. LevelOfDetails=1:
[image: LevelOfDetails = 1]

LevelOfDetails=3-6:
[image: LevelOfDetails = 3]
[image: LevelOfDetails = 6]

This is a function for generating meshes:

```
static void
GenerateTerrainMesh(world* World, noise_map* NoiseMap, float HeightMultiplier, int LevelOfDetail)
{
    int Width  = NoiseMap->Width;
    int Height = NoiseMap->Height;
    //float TopLeftX = (Width - 1)  / (-2.0f);
    //float TopLeftZ = (Height - 1) / ( 2.0f);

    if(LevelOfDetail < 0) LevelOfDetail = 0;
    if(LevelOfDetail > 6) LevelOfDetail = 6;

    int SimplificationInc = (LevelOfDetail == 0) ? 1 : (LevelOfDetail * 2);
    int VerticesPerLineX  = (Width  - 1) / SimplificationInc + 1;
    int VerticesPerLineY  = (Height - 1) / SimplificationInc + 1;

    InitializeMeshTerrain(World, VerticesPerLineX, VerticesPerLineX);

    int VertIndex = 0;
    int TrigIndex = 0;
    for(int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y += SimplificationInc)
    {
        for(int X = 0; X < Width; X += SimplificationInc)
        {
            World->Terrain.Vertices[VertIndex] = V3((float)X, HeightMultiplier * HeightFlatten(World->NoiseMap.Values[Y*World->NoiseMap.Width + X]).y * HeightMultiplier, (float)Y);
            World->Terrain.UVs[VertIndex]      = V2(X/(float)Width, Y/(float)Height);

            if((X < (Width - 1)) && (Y < (Height - 1)))
            {
                AddTriangle(World, &TrigIndex, VertIndex, VertIndex + VerticesPerLineX + 1, VertIndex + VerticesPerLineX);

                AddTriangle(World, &TrigIndex, VertIndex + VerticesPerLineX + 1, VertIndex, VertIndex + 1);
            }

            VertIndex += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And helper functions, but there should not be any errors:

```
static void
InitializeMeshTerrain(world* World, int Width, int Height)
{
    World->Terrain.VerticesCount = Width * Height;
    World->Terrain.FacesCount    = (Width - 1)*(Height - 1)*2;
    World->Terrain.UVCount       = Width * Height;

    World->Terrain.Faces    = (face*)malloc(sizeof(face)*World->Terrain.FacesCount);
    World->Terrain.Vertices = (v3*)malloc(sizeof(v3)*World->Terrain.VerticesCount);
    World->Terrain.UVs      = (v2*)malloc(sizeof(v2)*World->Terrain.UVCount);
}

static void
AddTriangle(world* World, int* Index, int a, int b, int c)
{
    World->Terrain.Faces[*Index].a = a;
    World->Terrain.Faces[*Index].b = b;
    World->Terrain.Faces[*Index].c = c;

    *Index += 1;
}
```

What problem could be there? Thank you.
UPD: I added some additional data to work with such as Mesh Data and Vertices Data for each LevelOfDetail:
Correct:
[LevelOfDetail=0](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HVZ7s-fB7ZU5fWKbWqMkXiZerUF8mqWe/view?usp=sharing)
Incorect 1:
[Incorect LevelOfDetail=1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y0h8vRrgv7uXLc0Lmw3VtlQ2tHwc8Ete/view?usp=sharing)
Incorect 4:
[Incorect LevelOfDetail=4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13KRIi0XecfDbGZVTb7Dx0i3qRC0NxPx0/view?usp=sharing)
Incorect 6:
[Incorect LevelOfDetail=6](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Hj2JLWKflnZjGzzm26PtEPADq_GpxHo/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Instead of looking at the images, you should dump out the data being used and numbers generated for the good and bad images and check for the differences.

Comment: At a guess, you've got some off-by-one logic in the code that iterates over the mesh. For example, a 5x5 grid of points is enough to define a 4x4 grid of squares. Reducing the detail by a factor of 2 gives you a 3x3 mesh of points defining a 2x2 grid of squares. Writing the code to traverse all of that can be very error-prone, since the vertex counts are not the powers of 2 you'd expect. You may wish to use indices based on squares rather than corners

Comment: I added generated Mesh and Vertices data for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like PaulMcKenzie mentioned, seams that I just used Even Numbers instead of Odd numbers and that was entirely of the problem. And even more, sometimes It couldn't work correctly, because I used too small numbers for generating mesh grid like 90 or 100. So, for correct working of this mesh algorithm Width should be divisible on 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 and 12, and then It should work pretty fine